# Is there a way to save all states for a simulation then restore from there when we restart Webots?

Tags: webots

I'm simulating a proto vehicle in webots. Currently, once the world is spawned, the vehicle's speed increases from 0 km/h to 100 km/h and will stay 100 km/h for the rest of the simulation.

After it reaches 100 km/h, I saved the world (*.wbt) and hope that when I use the saved world file in the future, the vehicle will skip the transient period (from 0 to 100 km/h) and starts with 100 km/h as its speed. In other words, I want the next time I spawn the world it would have the same behaviour as if I just pressed 'pause' and 'run' in the original file.

However, it seems like the 'save' function only saves the vehicle's location and orientation but not any physics behind. It will still start from zero speed and have a long transient time for it to reach 100.

Is there a way to tackle this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The short answer is no. Webots does save some physics states (like inertia) but device states (like the current force applied by a motor) are not saved. Anyway, this is actually a very complicated problem as your controller programs should also be able to save their current state and restore them upon load.

Comment: Thanks Olivier. Store the controller output and restore it next time is not very difficult for such a simple problem. Unfortunately, webots doesn't save device states. I don't know why is this so difficult given you could pause and rerun the simulation at any time. So I thought the current states should already be saved somewhere in memory. But anyway, thanks again for you reply!